# rails_admin customise dropdown with belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, belongs-to

I was trying to develop a basic rails_admin application. My usecase has Projects and Students.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to student
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many projects
end
```

As students can have the same name so, it is difficult to identify student while creating projects.
I needed to combine student's roll number and name to form a unique entry in the dropdown.
Thus I want the view for `Project` model to show list of students in the dropdown as `123 - John Doe` instead of just `John Doe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the method title

```
def title
  "#{roll_number} - #{full_name}"
end
```

As rails admin will try to display the object using first the name method and then the title method.

You can override globally this behavior like this:

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :description}
```

This would set the method description of any model as the one to be used to label objects.

You can also override per model like so:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'Team' do
    object_label_method do
      :custom_label_method
    end
  end

  def custom_label_method
    "Team #{self.name}"
  end
end
```

Reference: [The object_label_method method](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models#the-object_label_method-method)